# How to start MySQL after the year 2038?

Tags: mysql, linux

I am using MySQL 5.5. For some reason, I need to change the date of my system to after 2038. Unfortunately, the MySQL service won't start after the year 2038:

```
root@sd-84962:~# date
Sat Sep 24 18:41:32 CEST 2039
root@sd-84962:~# service mysql restart
stop: Unknown instance:
start: Job failed to start
root@sd-84962:~# date -s "Tue Sep 24 18:37:56 CEST 2015"
Thu Sep 24 18:37:56 CEST 2015
root@sd-84962:~# service mysql restart
stop: Unknown instance:
mysql start/running, process 22123
```

I do not have any tables in MySQL. 
I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a 64 bits system.

If I start mysqld manually, I get:

```
root@sd-84962:~# /usr/sbin/mysqld
610924 18:59:16 [ERROR] This MySQL server doesn't support dates later then 2038
610924 18:59:16 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I am using MySQL 64 bits:

```
mysql> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
```

What would be the workaround?

Comment: This is most likely related to the Linux Epoch bug.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: Could you maybe try and start `mysqld` manually, preferably with `strace`? As you can see, the system that starts/stops your services isn't very verbose when something fails to work. It might even be the culprit.

Comment: is this an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in the making?

Comment: do you use 64bit mysql?

Comment: It is a Year 2038 Unx timestamp issue, and you should have a 64 bit value for `time_t` which would need to be set up in your server , although I've no idea the details of how.

Comment: @Alex I use a 64bit mysql.

Comment: My MySQL server is empty, I do not have any tables in it.

Comment: File a bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com .  But don't expect it to be answered for a couple of decades.

Comment: The mariadb bug: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-16135